# Why am I getting this syntax error in my python-jinja2 app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am new to python and the google app engine. I am trying to create this app that fetches feed from yahoo pipes and displays it using jinja2 templates. However I am getting a syntax error and I am not understanding the reason behind it.

import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import jinja2
import logging

```
import feedparser  
import urllib

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_response(self, _template, **context):
        rv = self.jinja2.render_template(_template, **context)
        self.response.write(rv)

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        feed = feedparser.parse("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=1nWYbWm82xGjQylL00qv4w&_render=rss&textinput1=dogs" )

        feed = [{"link": item.link, "title":item.title, "description" : item.description} for item in feed["items"]
        context = {"feed" : feed, "search" : "dogs"}
        self.render_response('index.html', **context)

        def post(self):

            terms = self.request.get('search_term')

            terms = urllib.quote(terms)
            feed = feedparser.parse("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=1nWYbWm82xGjQylL00qv4w&_render=rss&textinput1=" + terms )

            feed = [{"link": item.link, "title":item.title, "description" : item.description} for item in feed["items"]]

            context = {"feed": feed, "search": terms}

            self.render_response('index.html', **context)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Here is the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Byte 1 Tutoral</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Data Pipeline Project Byte 1 Example</h1>
<form action="search" method="POST">
  Search Term: <input name="search_term" value={{search}}><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enter Search Term">
</form>
{% if search: %}
<p>Searching for {{search}}</p>
{% endif %}


<h2>Feed Contents</h2>
{% for item in feed %}
<a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a><br>
{{item.description|safe}}
<br>
{% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

and this is the error that I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\googleapps\ykelkar-byte1\main.py", line 38

    context = {"feed" : feed, "search" : "dogs"}

          ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

INFO     2014-01-16 23:15:25,845 module.py:612] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There should be one more ] at then end of line37:

```
feed = [{"link": item.link, "title":item.title, "description" : item.description} for item in feed["items"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two syntax errors:

1. missing `]` from the end of line 37
2. Incorrect indenting of the `post` function in `MainHandler`. Python syntax is indent sensitive, so it's very important to keep it consistent.

When looking for syntax errors, read the error message as carefully as possible. When you're starting out, a lot of it may not make much sense, but try and work out as much as possible. In this case, the reference to `Line 38` is a good tip. Read that line carefully, and if it looks okay, start looking above it.

It's also really handy to use an editor that support syntax highlighting, which will make these sorts of syntax errors immediately obvious.